# Login System in PHP

Tags: php

I've created a fully working login system and I've used cookies. But in my database, I have different types of users and would like a different pages to be displayed when the user logs in. How can I do that?

alert("Invalid Email or Password, Try Again!");window.history.go(-1);';
    }

    ?>

Comment: with a usertype field and a simple if block.

Comment: please elaborate, I've tried many ways

Comment: Show us what you've tried then

Comment: this is not a "please write some code for me" site. show what you already tried and we will help you to find your bugs. This is the reason for the downvotes of your question. please read the help to find out how to write a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a field in your database called 'usertype'
Then when you display the page, just do an if check against the usertype and display the correct page for each.

```
 if($user->usertype=='your_usertype1'){
    header('location: http://www.yoursite.com/dashboard1');
 } else if($user->usertype=='your_usertype2'){
    header('location: http://www.yoursite.com/dashboard2');
 } else {
    header('location: http://www.yoursite.com/dashboarddefault');
 }
```

Obviously though, on the actual pages, you'll want to also do a check, so that if a user goes to that page, and they ARENT that type of user, they will get redirected back or to wherever you want.

So on page dashboard1.php for instance you'll have.

```
 if($_SESSION['user']['usertype']!='your_usertype1'){
    header('location: http://www.yoursite.com/'); // direct back if the user isnt of this type
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may force `HTTP header Location` depending on user type. 
Say `$type` is your user type:

```
switch($type) {
  case 1:
    header('Location: user.php');
    break;
  case 2:
    header('Location: admin.php');
    break;
  case 3:
    header('Location: superadmin.php');
    break;
}
```